# How can I define that only one rule has to be executed in EasyRules?

Tags: java, rule-engine, easy-rules

I'm using [easy-rules](https://github.com/j-easy/easy-rules) to evaluate a set of  escenarios, each of them will execute  a different logic. I want to make sure that from all the rules registered only one gets executed, I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Facts facts = new Facts();
    facts.put("object", "value");

     Rules rules = new Rules();
     rules.register(new Rule1());
     rules.register(new Rule2());
     rules.register(new Rule3());

     RulesEngine rulesEngine=new DefaultRulesEngine();
     rulesEngine.fire(rules, facts);
}
```

In the previous example I want to ensure that if **Rule1** gets executed Rule2 and Rule3 won't be.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the further execution of rules once a match happens you need to configure the rule engine as follows :

```
RulesEngineParameters parameters = new RulesEngineParameters()
.skipOnFirstAppliedRule(true);
RulesEngine rulesEngine=new DefaultRulesEngine(parameters);
```

[From the Docs](https://github.com/j-easy/easy-rules/wiki/defining-rules-engine) :

[image]